# Is there a equivalent to #define DEBUG 0 declare by VS2017 with VisualMicro (arduino) project?

Tags: esp8266, esp32, visualstudio

Especially on ESP32*/8266, when you select debug (debug/release) : [image] as a target, VisualMicro detect it and start the *simple* debugger (without JTAG).

Do you know if when target is **debug**, is there a #define created somewhere by VS that could be use with #ifdef for example?

*ESP32 WROOM not ESP32 WROVER able to debug through USB double chanel

Comment: the documentation for visual micro is [here](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/User-Guide.aspx?doc=Project-Properties-Reference.html). the relevant section is "defines" about halfway down the page.

Comment: Ok but strange behaviour, need to be tested...

Comment: _DEBUG is define by VMicro in project parameter for each target with **Define _DEBUG Constant** set to 1 (0 by default)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YriDg.png

Comment: Visual studio Debug/release compilation target switch has no effect during compilation but affect intellisense #ifdef _DEBUG is grayed or not. So it is not easy to follow the real compile target. 

I suggest to set **Define _DEBUG Constant** to 1 in VS 'debug' compilation target project configuration and compilation will follow intellisense. But:

Another source [here][1]

  [1]: http://www.visualmicro.com/forums/YaBB.pl?num=1441308470

Comment: Another advise, clean the compiled file because VS doesn't detect **Define _DEBUG Constant** like another "standard" #define and your .cpp affected are not recompiled.